# Kohana 3.0 ORM WHERE - AND

Tags: php, orm, kohana-3

i want to make a corelated query using KO3 ORM, meaning that i want to have two conditions in an where:

now i have:

```
   public function get_free(){
            return $this->where('static_members_only','=',self::FREE);
    }
```

and i would like to have:

```
   public function get_free(){
            return $this->where('static_members_only','=',self::FREE) AND (some other conditions)
    }
```

is it possible?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`and_where()` is just a proxy to `where()`, so there is no difference whichever you choose to use. So

```
ORM::factory('model')
    ->where('something','=',$something)
    ->where('something_else','LIKE',$something_else)
    ->find_all();
```

will produce something like:

```
SELECT models.* 
FROM models 
WHERE something = '$something' 
AND something_else LIKE '$something_else'
```

Of course, all vars will be escaped / prepared so you don't have to worry about sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

can you try : Kohana's where_open() and where_close() methods ?
I think it should be done that way.

Comment: i don;t know abut these methods. are they kohana3's? also, can you give me an usage example? thank you!